# Why there is a garbage value is coming after strrev in C?

Tags: c, copy, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

There is my friend's code and I'm looking at that.
It's a simple example of using string's function and I feel that's not simple.
The problem is part (5).

This is code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *str1, char *str2) {
     str1 = strrev(str2);
     printf("%s\n\n", str1);    //**It's a test.**
}

int main() {
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];
    char str3[100];
    char str4[100];
    char temp[100];
    int len1, len2, len3, len4;

    //(1) use scanf()
    printf("(1) str1 : ");
    scanf("%s", &str1);
    printf("    str2 : ");
    scanf("%s", &str2);

    //(2) exchange, print()
    strcpy(temp, str1);
    strcpy(str1, str2);
    strcpy(str2, temp);
    printf("(2) str1=%s str2=%s\n", str1, str2);
    printf("len1=%d len2=%d\n", strlen(str1), strlen(str2));

    //(3) copy, print()
    strcpy(str3, str2);
    printf("(3) str3=%s\n", str3);

    //(4) strcat()
    strcat(str3, " ");
    strcat(str3, str1);
    strcat(str3, " My name is Elsa");
    printf("(4) str3=%s\n", str3);
    printf("len3=%d\n", strlen(str3));

    //(5) reverse(str4,  str3), print str4
    reverse(str4, str3);
    printf("(5) str4=%s\n", str4);    //**I don't know here**
    printf("len4=%d\n", strlen(str4));

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the result.

[image]

Why there is a garbage value?

Comment: To be able to put return value in function parameter you should pass a pointer to the type of value you want to return. so reverse should be `reverse(char **str1, char *str2)`. And make changes in code accordingly

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should not use `&` on arrays to read in the string: `scanf("%s", &str1);`. `str` already decays to a pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 1):

In this call

```
reverse(str4, str3);
```

the array `str4` is passed by value. So the expression `str4` used as an argument is converted to a temporary pointer to the first element of the array.

Thus the function `reverse` deals with this temporary object that is used as an initializer of the parameter of the function.

Changing this parameter (local variable of the function) does not influence on the content of the original array. It stays unchanged.

That is in this statement within the function

```
str1 = strrev(str2);
```

in fact the pointer `str2` is assigned to the pointer `str1`. The string pointed to by the pointer str2 will be changed. As for the pointer `str1` then it now points to the same string as the pointer `str1` and it will not be alive after exiting the function.

The function could be defined for example the following way if you want to change the string pointed to by the first parameter of the function

```
void reverse(char *str1, char *str2) {
     strcpy( str1, strrev(str2) );
     printf("%s\n\n", str1);    //**It's a test.**
}
```

However the function does not make great sense because it reverses two strings simultaneously.

If you wanted to copy the content of the string pointed to by the second parameter of the function into the array pointed to by the first parameter of the function then the function definition can look like

```
void reverse( char *str1, const char *str2 ) 
{
     strcpy( str1, str2 );

     strrev( s1 );

     printf("%s\n\n", str1);    //**It's a test.**
}
```

In this case the string pointed to by the pointer `str2` will be unchanged while the array pointed to by the pointer `str1` will get the reversed string pointed to by the pointer `str2`.

Comment: return strrev(str2) is more simple, no ?

Comment: @Hitokiri Is more simple compared with what?! We are speaking about the function reverse that accepts two arguments.

Comment: i mean, we can use the function with 1 argument, then return the result. So we do not need to worry about passing by pointer or value. Just a solution. I dont mean it's better or not, just simple to read, at my opinion

Comment: And, just a question. As i know strrev is non-standard. So should we use it ? Thanks

Comment: @Hitokiri no, if necessary, implement it by urself.

Answer (score 0):

Your function declaration should be instead as follows,

```
void reverse(char **str1, char *str2)
```

thereby not wanting to do operation just locally.